# Sql Server 2008 Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, relational-division

I have a table which contains UserId, ItemId and ItemName columns. I want to get some user's different items if that users have all items that specific user's items. How can I do that with sql server

Comment: Please provide some example data and desired results or improve your verbal explanation. I get that you want to find all users which have all of the items that a specific user does. But then what? You want to find all of the additional items that this complete set of users have that the specific user does not?

Comment: You mean this?: `SELECT ItemId, ItemName FROM Item WHERE UserId = @userid`

Comment: Also why does the table have both `ItemId` and `ItemName`. Should just have `ItemId` and you join to get the name.

Comment: Assume that there is an user with UserId = 1 and have two Items.These Items' ItemId are respectively 1 and 2. I will pass this UserId to procedure or statement query. If there are any users who have these two Items (ItemId=1 and 2) I want to get this users' other items

Answer (score 4):

You can use relational division to find all users that own all of the same items as UserId =1. [Some alternative approaches are discussed here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). Then you can use `EXCEPT` to subtract User 1's items.

```
SELECT  ItemId
FROM    UserItems U1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   UserItems U2
                     WHERE  UserId = 1
                            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                             FROM   UserItems U3
                                             WHERE  U1.UserId = U3.UserId
                                                    AND U2.ItemId = U3.ItemId ) )
EXCEPT
SELECT  ItemId
FROM    UserItems
WHERE   UserId = 1
```

Comment: +1 First time I ever seen a use for EXCEPT. Thanks for the refresher.